# How to run programs in an external console with Sublime Text in Windows system?

Tags: c++, windows, console, mingw, sublimetext

I managed to configure Sublime Text 2 for C++ and I can now compile my code (using the MinGW compiler).

Unfortunately, the Sublime Text console can't support any kind of input for C++.

I want to open my compiled program in an external console (Window's terminal for instance).
I tried to use "call" or "cmd" but couldn't make it work. (it still opens the file in the console)

Here's my build configuration:

```
{
"cmd": ["C:\\MinGW\\bin\\mingw32-g++.exe", "-Wall", "-time", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name"],
"cmd": ["call", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
"selector": "source.c",
"shell": true,
"encoding": "latin1"
}
```

Comment: Could you try setting `shell` to `false`.

Comment: It doesn't work when I put ``shell`` to ``false``
(even the compiler doesn't work when I do that)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try with this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Dev-Cpp\\bin\\mingw32-g++.exe", "-static", "-Wall", "-time", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name.exe", "&&", "start", "$file_base_name"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.c",
    "shell": true,
    "encoding": "latin1"
}
```

The trick is to execute the generated file using the "start" command, which forces the file to open in a new cmd window, and to put everything inside the first cmd definition (using the && in order to execute the two commands), because if you define more than one cmd array, they overwrite.

Comment: This works perfectly.

Thank you for the great explanation too, didn't know about the "start" command (and I might often use it in the future) !

Comment: @FacundoJ, How would I do that in Mac or Linux?

Comment: @Tareq see RichS's answer below :D

Comment: This works great but this doesn't work when I take inputs from a file and output to it another file " freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
 freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);"

Answer (score 12):

@FacundoJ: On Mac, you can use Terminal to run the app externally.  In C++.sublime-build, change the cmd so that instead of just running the compiled output, it launches it in Terminal.

Change from:

```
"cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
```

To:

```
"cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && open -a Terminal.app '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
```

Comment: Is it the same for linux?

Comment: No, it won't work for Linux as Terminal is a Mac app. But, I'm sure there is an equivalent mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer allows you to execute the program in Windows CMD and accept input. **But once the program execution is over, the cmd window will be closed immediately before you can see clearly the output**.

I think you should try the following solution, **which keeps the CMD window open after executing the program, so that you can examine your result**.

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "g++ -Wall -std=c++11 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe\"",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [   // run in the sublime text console
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd":"\"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
        },
        // run in the Windows cmd
        {
            "name": "Run in cmd",
             // the following two settings are all valid, choose one you prefer
            "shell_cmd":   "start cmd /k  $file_base_name "
            // "shell_cmd":   "start \"$file_base_name\" call $file_base_name"
        }
    ]
}
```

First press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to compile the program, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and choose `run in cmd` option, which will run the program in system CMD instead of the Sublime Text console.

The above settings are tested on Windows 8.1, and should also work on Windows 7 and Windows 10 out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

In the accepted answer from @FacundoJ you compile the program everytime you run it. This is not always necessary (i.e. when you just modify some external resources or play with main args). In that case I recommend this settings:

```
{
  "cmd": ["g++", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name.exe"],
  "working_dir": "${project_path:$folder}",
  "selector": "source.cpp",
  "shell": true,
  "variants": [{
    "name": "Run",
    "cmd": ["start", "", "$file_base_name"]
  }]
}
```

(Assuming you have C:\MinGW\bin in your PATH) so you can use it like

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> Compile the program
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> Run it (after compiled, of course)

**Note1** Note the empty string after `start` command: it [should be used](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

**Note2** you should use `.cpp` suffix, or C89 syntax is used by default (at least with MinGW g++ compiler)

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu

```
{
"cmd": ["g++ ${file} && xterm -hold -e ./a.out"], 
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c++",
"shell": true,
}
```

what this build-system does is compiles the .cpp file and open the output file in xterm.

-->if you want the output to open in **gnome-terminal**,create a profile

In gnome-terminal, go to Edit -> Profile Preferences->Click the Command tab. Select 'Hold the terminal open' from the drop-down menu labelled When command exits.You should create a new profile for that

and then replace "cmd" with

```
 "cmd": ["g++ ${file} && gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=PROFILENAME -e ./a.out"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is WORKING !!**

```
{"cmd": ["g++", "-Wall", "-ansi", "-pedantic-errors", "$file_name", "-o", 
"${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k" , "$file_base_name"],
"selector": "source.cpp",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"shell": true}
```

- Just goto Tools>Build Sytem>New build
  System..."C++.sublime-build"...and **Must SAVE it as ALL FILES**
- Select that build

**Just enter (ctrl+b)** to see an elevated command prompt open and give your inputs like other IDE's.