# Sublime Text 3 C++ Build System for OS X

Tags: c++, macos, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 in OS X (Mountain Lion). I am trying to build and run a simple hello world application in Sublime Text 3. It's working fine, but when I am taking any input, it's not prompting for any console input. It just directly runs and shows output without taking any input.

Here's my build profile:

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Sample program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number;

    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << "You entered: " << number;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Code in Sublime text 2 ( Mac OS X )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690657/running-code-in-sublime-text-2-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5219), ST simply doesn't allow for interactive builds.

**Edit**:

Check out this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601423/how-to-run-programs-in-an-external-console-with-sublime-text?rq=1) for a workaround.