# Running Code in Sublime text 2 ( Mac OS X )

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, scanf

I'm trying to run C code in sublime text 2 and i've noticed that scanf seems to be completely ignored, although it works fine in both xcode and in the terminal with gcc.
I personally prefer the look of sublime text, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed in several questions on SO, and the [unofficial docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/index.html) are currently being updated to more clearly state this: neither ST2 nor ST3 supports direct input to programs running within build systems *inside* Sublime Text: C/C++'s `scanf` and colleagues do not work, nor do Python's `raw_input` (Python 2) or `input` (Python 3), Ruby's `gets`, Java's `Scanner` class, etc. This is a fundamental limitation of the program.

However, it can be worked around in two ways. First, you can run your build system in a terminal. Second, if you are using an interpreted language like JavaScript, Python, Ruby, Perl, Scheme and all the associated Lisp-like languages like Clojure, Erlang, Haskell, PHP, R, etc., you can check out the excellent [`SublimeREPL`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) plugin. You can open a REPL for interactive programming, and send programs (or bits of them) to it and interact with them just as on the command line. Documentation is [here](http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/).