# EOFError in Python, REPL didn't work

Tags: python, sublimetext2, eoferror

So I am fairly new to writing in Python (and using Sublime 2 on a Windows 8.1), and I kept getting:

```
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I made a very simple program:

```
f = raw_input('Enter a number')
print f
```

However even this returns:

```
Enter a numberTraceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\\*****\Documents\Programming\test.py", line 1, in <module>
f = raw_input('Enter a number')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

Many other solutions had installing SublimeREPL, I installed this and the problem persists. Other solutions don't seem relevant.

Any ideas what is causing this error?

Comment: Are  you running this from within Sublime? or directly via the Python interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you run python scripts inside sublime, it [doesn't handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27772814/2387772) the `raw_input` part. You have three options:

1. install a package that deals with this (such as sublimeREPL which you mention didn't work - so either a problem with the package or - more probable - you didn't install it correctly)
2. run the script from the windows cmd
3. avoid using `raw_input` entirely (pretty much no one uses it anyway)