# Sublime 3 switch focus to output panel

Tags: sublimetext3

I run a simple Python script that asks for user input:

`name = input("What's your name?")`

In Sublime Text 3, I use Cmd + B to run this and I see the prompt in the output panel. Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch my focus to the prompt?

Comment: The *output* window is exactly what it says, you can't *input* anything. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690657/running-code-in-sublime-text-2-mac-os-x)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Code in Sublime text 2 ( Mac OS X )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690657/running-code-in-sublime-text-2-mac-os-x)

Comment: Neither of these comments is correct. He's not asking about input and it's not a duplicate of the linked page. He wants to *switch focus* to the output panel, which does not have focus by default after pressing Ctrl+B. He is looking for something like [this](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-set-focus-to-exec-output-panel/26689).

Answer (score 0):

See https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-set-focus-to-exec-output-panel/26689/2.

In summary:

1. Click menu `Tools > Developer > New Plugin`, save the below code inside the newly created file.

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class ExecOutputFocusCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command('show_panel', args={'panel': 'output.exec'})
        self.window.focus_view(self.window.find_output_panel("exec"))
```

2. Make a new key binding (`Preference > Key Bindings`) like this:

```json
{"keys": ["ctrl+9"], "command": "exec_output_focus"},
```

Then you can focus on the build output by click ctrl+9.

Comment: This is the way. Here's a [more general purpose solution](https://github.com/randy3k/Terminus/issues/302#issuecomment-1137223130) that also lets you toggle between the panel and the view.